# How to remove backgridjs row to display new rows?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

This appends a new set of rows to the original grid:

```
var refreshgrid = function(){
    var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
      columns: columns,
      collection: ter
    });

    // Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
   // $("#example-1-result").append(grid.remove());
    $("#example-1-result").prepend(grid.render().$el);
}
```

thus, everytime I call it, it appends to the grid rather than overwriting it, which is what I want. 
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` instead of `.append()/.prepend()` as `.html()` removes/overwrites the old value with new one :

```
var refreshgrid = function(){
    var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
      columns: columns,
      collection: ter
    });

    // Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
    $("#example-1-result").html(grid.render().$el);
}
```